# What is facultyawards.org?

Tags: tenure-track, awards

I recently received an unsolicited email from https://facultyawards.org. I tried Google to get a better sense of just what this group intends, but I couldn't find much insight. My question is simply this:

> What is the origin of this group and do their awards carry any merit towards a typical promotion for faculty tenure, etc?

Comment: I did not know this site either, but I'll be damned if what boils down to a popularity contest ("cast your votes for your peers") holds any relevance for tenure review or promotion.

Comment: Buried deep in the web site is a description of a "high-quality leather-bound volume" for each discipline that they plan to produce and offer for sale.  It's a typical "Who's Who" scam.

Comment: If it appears too good to be true... it usually isn't true.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the origin of this group

Nobody knows.

> and do their awards carry any merit towards a typical promotion for faculty tenure or promotion?

### No.

At least, I certainly hope not.  Nobody in their right mind would trust an award of completely unknown provenance.

I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if *everyone* who signs up is selected for an award and then immediately offered a high-quality leather-bound archival book listing your achievements and those of other winners, all for the absurdly low price of $500, but only if you reply in the next fifteen seconds with your credit card information.  See also ["Who's Who"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who's_Who_scam).

Comment: Yup, definite scam site. Avoid like the plague.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I only hope this shows up on Google as prominently as the tripe the originators of the spam have plastered there.